# AngularJS - Why are dependencies with modules necessary?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, visual-studio-2013

Can you tell me why it is recommended to add dependency modules to the creation of a module?

I've tried to run the code without adding the modules **TodoApp.controllers** and **TodoApp.services**. Even though I removed them, everything ran perfectly .. (I call a service via those two files)

### app.js

```
// Injects all the needed modules
var TodoApp = angular.module("TodoApp", [
        "ngRoute",
        "ngResource",
        "TodoApp.controllers",
        "TodoApp.services"
]).
    config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/', { controller: "listCtrl", templateUrl: 'list.html' }).
            otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
    });
```

### Update

Thank you for your response! :)

Unfortunately, those files don't share a common variable:

That was actually the reason why I didn't understand the set of problem. For me, this code gets stored in nowhere. Could it be because of the dot notation in the naming?

### controller.js

```
angular.module('TodoApp.controllers', []).
    controller('listCtrl', function ($scope, $location, todoApiService) {
        $scope.todos = todoApiService.getMyTodos().query();
});
```

### services.js

```
angular.module('TodoApp.services', []).
    factory('todoApiService', function ($resource) {
        var todoApi = {};

        todoApi.getMyTodos = function () {
            return $resource('/api/todo/:id', { id: '@id' }, { update: { method: 'PUT' } });
        };

    return todoApi;
});
```

Comment: Are those files added after the module / app.js file? If so then there's no need to inject them. Typically I only inject OTHER modules (lets say global / helper ones) into my current app module. Those modules might include their own directives / factories / etc

Comment: that's correct! so the default loading order of the html handles this whole stuff if I put it into the right order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to inject controllers & services since they have to be part of a `module` anyway.

You *could* have them labeled like so in the other files:

```
TodoApp.controllers(/* ... */)
TodoApp.services(/* ... */)
```

They are already attaching themselves to the module because of the `TodoApp` variable (which in-turn is `angular.module('TodoApp')`.

It looks like you call the module directly each time:

```
angular.module('TodoApp.controllers', []).
    controller('listCtrl', /* etc etc */ );
```

Each way, you are simply adding more things (in typical dot notation) to your overall Module, and angular understand it's `TodoApp` since you are starting it with that.

But sometimes you'll see people inject *other* modules, in a way inheriting the modules controllers / directives / services / etc.

```
var HelperModule = angular.module('HelperModule', /*...*/);
HelperModule.directive('headerLinks', /*...*/);
HelperModule.factory('BaseFactory', /*...*/);
// etc etc

var TodoApp = angular.module("TodoApp", ["HelperModule"]); // <-- Module injected

// TodoApp now contains all the directives/etc from that module!
```

Hope that helps!